# How to refactor this legacy code snippet to make it extensible?

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented-design, refactoring, clean-code

I've come across a method resembling the below snippet.

```
public void process(Data row) {

    Value value1 = row.getValue1();
    Value value2 = row.getValue2();
    boolean saved = false;

    if (value1 != null) {

        if (relevantValues.contains(value1)) {
            addRow(value1, row, only1collection);

            if (relevantValues.contains(value2)) {
                addRow(value2, row, values12collection);
            }

            repository.save(row);
            stats.increment();
            saved = true;
        }

    }

    if (relevantValues.contains(value2)) {
        addRow(value2, row, only2collection);
        if (!saved) {
            repository.save(row);
            stats.increment();
        }
    }

}

private void addRow(Value date, Data row, Map<Value, List<Data>> mapping) {
    mapping.computeIfAbsent(date, (p) -> new ArrayList());
    mapping.computeIfPresent(date, (d, rows) -> {
        rows.add(row);
        return rows;
    });
}
```

In the above code, the method `process` will be called for each row of some data file and based on the value in a couple of fields, the row should be added to any or all of the 3 collections.

The code,

```
        repository.save(row);
        stats.increment();
```

seems like I'm coupling two independent functionalities/aspects into kind of "lifecycle"/business logic of row processing. I can not straight up use decorator pattern here as these two steps need to be performed conditionally and only once per row. Moreover, if I want to extend the functionality, for example, send an email after incrementing stats, the code will look like,

```
        repository.save(row);
        stats.increment();
        sendEmail(row);
```

This clearly violates the Open-Closed principle. I'm thinking whether it'd be a good idea to take a `Set<RowProcessor>` and execute them when the row is interesting. What would be a good way or a pattern to organize this?

The nested `if` conditions are not looking good. Any general principles, patterns to make it more functional?

How can I eliminate the `if(!saved)` check?

Any other suggestions, improvements are more than welcome. If you know any book that gives practical guidance for refactoring/cleaning code in scenarios like this, please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

I personally don't consider the code to be that bad.

First thing I consider is that it is quite feasible to write automated tests for it. You should definitely do it before you start any refactoring. Having tests would allow you to experiment around getting rid of the `saved` flag. Or you can realize it is not as bad as it seems. I would consider following issues to be more pressing than the flag.

Next thing that was quite confusing at first notice is the `addRow` method. You should at least make the `mapping` parameter to be first one. If this was C#, it would make sense to make it into extension method. In case of Java creating your own structure, that encapsulates the `Map` and exposes the `addRow` method would be best option.

And your problem with extensibility around `repository` can be solved simply. Just make `repository` an interface. Then, you can use [Composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) to implement multiple different ways how rows are "stored" and [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) for statistics. It will also make it easier to test, as it can be mocked/faked.

Last note about OCP. OCP should be applied strategically. Making code open against changes makes it more complex. You should be careful about adding complexity where it is not needed. In your case, you have identified one area where making your code more open will make things easier, while not adding that much complexity. But you should be careful about creating new abstractions you only think might be needed.

Answer (score 3):

Before worrying about extensibility, what I'd do is put this thing under unit test to be sure I'm not making any unintended changes and rework it until this [arrow anti pattern](http://wiki.c2.com/?ArrowAntiPattern) goes away.

```
public void process(Data row) {

    Value value1 = row.getValue1();
    Value value2 = row.getValue2();  

    Boolean relevant1 = ( (value1 != null) && relevantValues.contains(value1) );
    Boolean relevant2 = ( relevantValues.contains(value2) );

    if (relevant1) {
        addRow(value1, row, only1collection);
    }

    if (relevant1 && relevant2) {
        addRow(value2, row, values12collection); 
    }   

    if (relevant2) {
        addRow(value2, row, only2collection); 
    }

    if (relevant1 || relevant2) {
        store.update(row);
    }
}
```

That's a tad more readable. Since the original code, thankfully, had no [temporal coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/) between its lines they could each be wrapped in whatever conditionals pertained to them and rearranged at will. Here's the history of simple changes that got me here:

[1. Put each `addRow()` in its own structure](https://pastebin.com/Hi0jdJ8H)
[2. Collapse to multiline boolean logic and group similar sections together](https://pastebin.com/dphqTEW5)
[3. Turn "saved" bool into an "else if"](https://pastebin.com/SKkxc6i1)
[4. Turn "else if" into an OR](https://pastebin.com/hy4cYCiT)
[5. Simplify conditionals with boolean vars](https://pastebin.com/wMJ7NYVU)

Now you may be looking at this and wondering "what is store?" It's whatever you'd like it to be.

```
public interface Store {
    public void update(Row row);
}

public StoreDefault implements Store {
    public void update(Row row);
        repository.save(row);
        stats.increment();
    }
}

public StoreReport implements Store {
    public void update(Row row);
        repository.save(row);
        stats.increment();
        email.send(row);
    }
}
```

I've used [The Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) but there are many other patterns (and non-patterns) that could work as well. Since changes in how `process()` concludes can be made by creating new `store` types, this respects [OCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) just fine.  The important thing is that `process()` doesn't have to know what was used. That not-knowing is what lets the polymorphism work. And polymorphism is the heart and soul of Object Oriented Programming.

Answer (score 1):

To me it look like `repository` and `stats` should live in a different object:

```
class RepositoryStatistics{
  private final Repository repository;
  private final Statistics statistics;
  private final Collection<Row.ID> savedRows = new HashSet<>(); // no duplicates;
  RepositoryStatistics(Repository repository, Statistics statistics){
     this.repository = repository;
     this.statistics = statistics;
  }

  public void save(Row row){ 
      if(!savedRows.contains(row.getId()){
        repository.save(row);
        stats.increment();
      }
  }
}
```

But this does not solve the *extensibility* issue.

I'd introduce a *functional interface*:

```
class RepositoryStatistics{
  @FunctionalInterface
  interface RepositorySaveAction{
     void afterSaveOf(Row row);
  }
  private final List<RepositorySaveAction> repositorySaveActions; // keep order..
  RepositoryStatistics(Repository repository,RepositorySaveAction ...repositorySaveActions) {
     this.repository = repository;
     this.repositorySaveActions = Arrays.asList(repositorySaveActions);
  }
  public void save(Row row){ 
      if(!savedRows.contains(row.getId()){
        repository.save(row);
        for(RepositorySaveAction repositorySaveAction:repositorySaveActions)
            repositorySaveAction.afterSaveOf(row);
      }
  }
}
```

And `stats.increment()` would be my first implementation:

```
// somehere in your code
RepositoryStatistics repo = 
   new RepositoryStatistics(realRepository,
      row->stats.increment(),
      row->mailer.send(row));
```

Answer (score 1):

The nested `if` can be transformed as follows. There is a name for this coding style: *predicated execution*, or [*predication*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predication_(computer_architecture)) for short. You will literally see low-level code written in this style.

The new code computes a bunch of "clairvoyant" bools. These bools will foretell (dictate) the rest of execution flow, before executing any commands with side-effects.

The bool names are super-verbose for web viewing only. Choose shorter names according to your own convention. Example:

- replace "isValueOneNotNull" with "nn1",
- replace "isValueOneRelevant" with "r1",
- replace "needAddToBothOneTwoCollection" with "c12"

It is assumed that "relevantValues.contains(*)" is side-effect free. If it has side-effects, you should not be refactoring the code at all.

Note that the code below is not exactly the same as yours - I changed the behavior slightly because of what I suspect to be bugs (for lack of symmetry). If you know that your code is correct then my code is probably slightly wrong.

```
// existing code

Value value1 = row.getValue1();
Value value2 = row.getValue2();

// new code

final bool isValueOneNotNull = 
    value1 != null;

final bool isValueTwoNotNull = 
    value2 != null;             // your code doesn't check this

final bool isValueOneRelevant = 
    isValueOneNotNull && relevantValues.contains(value1);

final bool isValueTwoRelevant = 
    isValueTwoNotNull && relevantValues.contains(value2);

final bool needAddToOnlyOneCollection = 
    isValueOneRelevant && !isValueTwoRelevant;

final bool needAddToOnlyTwoCollection = 
    !isValueOneRelevant && isValueTwoRelevant;

final bool needAddToBothOneTwoCollection = 
    isValueOneRelevant && isValueTwoRelevant;

// There are two ways to compute the next bool.

final bool needSaveTheMoreComplicatedWay = 
    needAddToOnlyOneCollection ||
    needAddToOnlyTwoCollection ||
    needAddToBothOneTwoCollection;

// The simplified way. Should be logically equivalent.

final bool needSave = 
    isValueOneRelevant || isValueTwoRelevant; 

// The next few bools are optional - to illustrate
// how you can customize and add additional logic.

final bool needIncrementStats = needSave && statisticianHasBeenHired;
final bool needSendEMail = needSave && internetIsNotDown;

// actual "execution"

if (needAddToOnlyOneCollection) { 
    addRow(value1, row, only1collection);
}
if (needAddToOnlyTwoCollection) { 
    addRow(value2, row, only2collection);
}
if (needAddToBothOneTwoCollection) { 
    addRow(value2, row, values12collection);
}

bool saveSucceeded = false;
if (needSave) {
    repository.save(row);
    // if the next line is reached, I suppose no exception was thrown.
    saveSucceeded = true;
}

if (needIncrementStats) {
    stats.increment();
}

if (needSendEMail) {
    sendEmail(row);
}
```

Comment: Totally not less readable than the original code